# Accuracy of "Region Monitoring" on iOS 6

Tags: ios, location, ios-simulator, region, cllocation

I'm trying to make a location-based app that requires constant updating of the location after opening. I was looking for a way to keep the location in the background when the app is closed and I found that is not the best way because it would drain the battery very quickly from any iPhone.

To cut a long story short I found with the "Region Monitoring" as I have understood they are the same as Apple uses for their App "Reminders" that also works with location. Then I used that option to test my app and I realize that in the simulator "never" enters the method "didEnterRegion" despite it is correctly created:

```
-(void) locationManager: (CLLocationManager *) manager didEnterRegion: (CLRegion *) region
 {
     NSLog (@ "entering the region");
     CLLocation * location1 = manager.location;
     CLLocation * location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: latitud.doubleValue longitude: longitud.doubleValue];
 }
```

I finally realized that the method is called but only when I walked away much of the area and I was back to the area, indicating that it did not work because I was already in that location (all this in the simulator), the strange thing is that it was not, the location of the simulator was miles from the region to monitor! Which leads me to think it is problem of accuracy, despite creating the region with 50 or 100 meter radius was spreading the 3 or 4 km, so I was useless.

Has anyone experienced this knows if iOS 6 simulator has this error or if precision problem? I don't have a Developer Licence yet to test it directly on my iPhone and I do not want to buy it yet because my app is far from finished, I appreciate any help on this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing actual ground testing. Region monitoring accuracy varies a lot depending on the test location.

Second option is to use region monitoring to just wake up the app and start standard location service. To do this you need permission to run the app in background. Apple may not approve this. Our app got rejected using this approach.

Answer (score 2):

DidEnterRegion and ExitRegion is not very accurate. Around +, - 150m accuracy.

But -(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
is very accurate. Use this to find out your regions have  coordinates/current location

```
CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

 if ([self.ARegionYouSetBeforeHand containsCoordinate:currentLocation.coordinate])
{
 //you arrived at this region!!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Region monitoring works (generally) on the same basis as the "significant location change" location service. That is, it uses cell tower location; Apple suggests you can usually expect accuracy around 1km, but warns that actual accuracy will vary with the density of cell towers in your area. You can find more background on this topic in the [WWDC videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/) on Core Location.

It might be feasible -- I haven't tried -- to use Region Monitoring to (wake up your app and) get a general guess at the user's location, then use a higher accuracy mode in `CLLocationManager` to get a more precise fix.

Comment: The same thing I tried, and yes... It works, but for me is something a little "inelegant". Even I tried to force to call the method "didEnterRegion" when I created the region and compare the distance between the user location and the region point and if this distance is more than 1 km then I call directly to the "didEnterRegion" method, but that does not looks good to me. And for my App 1 km is too much! I need an accuracy maximum of 200 meters.

Comment: In my own test, I have found region monitoring to be quite inaccurate. I too also experienced the accuracy was a few kilometres off. Apple did say you need to cross a region and stay within that region for around 20 seconds before it's considered a region crossing.

Comment: Yes, @Zhang, in my investigation I discovered that you need cross a region in order to enter to the "didEnterRegion" method, but even so in the documentation Apple did said that "Region Monitoring" is for create alerts by places like "laundries" o something like that. I expected that the accuracy was enought for a real utility

Comment: Apple's reminder app worked pretty well when I tried it. It triggered each time I was at my house, as expected. Although, I am not sure if they're using region monitoring or not. In my own test, it also triggered each time but can miss quite often. You're not going to get laser accurate data. My own tests shows that I am about 500 metres off most of the time, my radius is from 150 to 200 metres.

Comment: Since you rickster seems to have a lot of reputation can I ask you this? Even in my iPhone, the radius of a few meter ends of being radius of hundreds of meter. So a destination is arrived, when a user enters 100m radius instead of intended 5m. Here is the clarification question I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417818/didenterregion-called-with-larger-radius-ios

Comment: The above thread says the accuracy of didEnterRegion and didExitRegion is ~200 m

Answer (score 0):

At finish I realize that the accuracy of Region Monitoring is good enought for the most purposes, but in the simulator can be tricky because it not have GPS or cellphone hardware, anyway when I used "region monitoring" in my device even in a simulation route the function works correctly.

And for more accuracy even,  I invoked the method "startUpdatingLocation" of the CLLocationManager into the method "didEnterRegion", that works okey for me.

Comment: Even with real iPhone, the region with a few meters radius ends up being region with hundreds meter radius.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue with Region Monitoring on iPhone 5C with cellular tower mobile data, disabling the WiFi, I was used to get didEnterRegion called very soon, when I was 1.95 Km away from the monitoring point for which I kept region radius of 100.0 meters. Which is too early.

Apple has some Threshold value determined by the hardware and the location technologies that are currently available. So for me it might be around 1800 meters early value.

I suggest to keep radius minimum (say 25.0 for 500.0 region) OR if it is so precious notification, use didUpdateLocations delegate method and determine your region and notify the same.

Regards,
Kaushik

Answer (score 0):

I found that the built in region monitoring wasn't accurate enough for my needs. If you need higher accuracy, first set your accuracy appropriately, and then you can use something like this:

(Uses the same method as @coolcool1994, but a little more in-depth and using Swift 2.1. Remember to set up `CLLocationManager` and its Delegate (where the functions below would reside), and start receiving location updates)

```
var activeRegions = Set<String>()
var monitoredRegions = [
  CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0),
    radius: 300, identifier: "Region1"),
  CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0),
    radius: 300, identifier: "Region2")
]

func manuallyUpdateActiveRegionsFromLocation(location: CLLocation){
  // Optionally explicitly reject unwanted location updates
  // Setting the location manager delegate's desiredAccuracy should be enough
  let maxOldTime = 300 //5 minutes
  let minAccuracy = 300 //300 metres
  if abs(location.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow) > maxOldTime
    || location.horizontalAccuracy > minAccuracy {
      return
  }

  for monitoredRegion in monitoredRegions {
    if monitoredRegion.containsCoordinate(location.coordinate) {
      activeRegions.insert(monitoredRegion.identifier)
    } else {
      activeRegions.remove(monitoredRegion.identifier)
    }
  }

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
  if let location = locations.last {
    manuallyUpdateActiveRegionsFromLocation(location)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pre-Defined GPS Accuracy on MK MapView**

1. kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation – Uses the highest possible
   level of accuracy augmented by additional sensor data.
2. kCLLocationAccuracyBest – The highest    recommended level of
   accuracy for devices running on battery power.
3. kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters - Accurate to within 10 meters.
4. CLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters – Accurate to within 100    meters.
5. kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer – Accurate to within one    kilometer.
6. kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers – Accurate to    within three
   kilometers.

**Usage:**

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    //MapView Location
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
```