# didEnterRegion called with larger radius (iOS)

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, clregion

I want didEnterRegion to be called with much precision, but I wasn't able to do so. Here is what I have done: I used the best values of distanceFilter and desiredAccuracy (most precise GPS settings according to Apple) and have a destination CLCircularRegion (Subclass of CLRegion).

```
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLCircularRegion *Destination;
self.Destination = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.907691, -69.963158) radius:5 identifier:@"Destination"];

[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.Destination];
```

The problem is when I am like 150m away from this destination, didEnterRegion gets called. Also around similar distance away didExitRegion gets called. I want didEnter and didExit region to be called when I am 5 m away, not 150m away, as I have specified with initiation of CLCircularRegion. Does anyone have a solution? Precision is what I need, and 150m instead of 5m is too inaccurate for me. Thanks ton -

(I used iPhone 4S to Test)

Comment: I guess it is limited technically and such high accuracy can't be achieved:" ... realize that region events may not happen immediately... you can assume that the minimum distance is approximately 200 meters." cited from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW2)

Comment: That's what I think it is, but the funny thing is that with -(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations and using containsCoordinate method of ClRegion, you can get very accurate result of whether you are in that region or not. It makes no sense to me how didenterRegion and didExitRegion is so not inaccurate. There gonna be a way to make it work, because Apple devices are very capable of this sort of accuracy. With wifi and cellular connection combined, I believe there could be a way to make this more accurate.

Comment: If no other solution is there, I will give the bounty to you Volker.

Comment: still 7 days and probably someone with an working answer... would make me feel better. I am working on some CLLocation code right now, and maybe i can fit in testing your problem and looking for a solution...

Comment: btw, did you test on a device or in simulator?

Comment: Yes I have. I have tested on my simulator. Same results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While in theory accuracies of 5m are possible with the current GPS+ technical gear, it may be that Apple prevents such accuracy for region monitoring for various reasons.

One is that they always want a good user experience and the 5m accuracy you want is within the accuracy range you will often get from the GPS readings. Thus leaving such a small region could also be on account of lower accuracy readings while the user is still within the region. Apple does cover up for such errors by setting thresholds for posting regionEnter or regionExit notifications. From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW2):

> When testing your region monitoring code in iOS Simulator or on a device, realize that region events may not happen immediately after a region boundary is crossed. To prevent spurious notifications, iOS doesn’t deliver region notifications until certain threshold conditions are met. Specifically, the user’s location must cross the region boundary, move away from the boundary by a minimum distance, and remain at that minimum distance for at least 20 seconds before the notifications are reported.
>
> The specific threshold distances are determined by the hardware and the location technologies that are currently available. For example, if Wi-Fi is disabled, region monitoring is significantly less accurate. However, for testing purposes, you can assume that the minimum distance is approximately 200 meters

Nevertheless since you can ask for high accuracy readings Apple should also take that into account. The alternative might be - as you commented - to use didUpdateLocation: and determine if inside or outside the region. That way you could include a test for location accuracy and only accept an exit/entry when horizontal accuracy is good enough.

Comment: Yes, thank you Volker, you get my bounty. I can award the bounty in 9 hours, so I will do so after 9 hours. Thanks so much. I am using didupdatelocation, and I will post further if this works out for very precise GPS reading to simulate did enter and did exit.